# Ion-slides full height - Ionic 3

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using the `ion-slides` component and when the slide content height is bigger than the view I cannot scroll down to see the rest of the slide content. So, how should I scroll down to see the rest of the content on the slide?

I'm using this **htlm**

```
   <ion-content> 

      <ion-slides>
        <ion-slide>
          <div>...</div>
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>  

    </ion-content>
```

What I have tried is:

```
    <ion-content>        
      <ion-slides style="height: 100%" >
        <ion-slide style="height: 100vh" >
          <div>...</div>
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>       
    </ion-content>

   <ion-content>        
      <ion-slides style="height: 100vh" >
        <ion-slide style="height: 100%" >
          <div>...</div>
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>       
    </ion-content>

   <ion-content>        
      <ion-slides style="height: 100%" >
        <ion-slide>
          <div>...</div>
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>       
    </ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you use `height{100vh}` ?

Comment: Hello, I already tried 100vh and 100% in the style of the ion-slides and ion-slide.. the results remain the same..

Comment: Please add your code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: Hi, I just edited the post..  I only have tried some changes in the css but nothing seems to happen..

Comment: so can you just limit the height of your slides or your slides have height set to something high and you can't really influence that? what  do you want? to scale it down to fit or enable scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `ion-slide` where you want a vertical scroll

```
<ion-slide>
    <ion-content>
         <ion-infinite-scroll>
            <!--code here-->
         </ion-infinite-scroll>
    </ion-content>
</ion-slide>
```

in your `.scss`

```
.slide-zoom {
    height: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ionic 4 It is slightly different...

You need to set scrollEvents to true in the `html` file

```
<ion-content [scrollEvents]="true">
  <ion-slides #slides (ionSlideDidChange)="onSlideChanged()">
    <ion-slide>
      <ion-infinite-scroll>
        <!-- slide 1 -->
      </ion-infinite-scroll>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      <ion-infinite-scroll>
        <!-- slide 2 -->
      </ion-infinite-scroll>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

in the `ts` file

```
.
.
.
@ViewChild("slides", { static: false }) slides: IonSlides;
@ViewChild(IonContent, { static: false }) content: IonContent;
.
.
async onSlideChanged(): Promise<void> {
    this.content.scrollToTop();
}
```

in the `global.scss` file

```
ion-infinite-scroll {
  height: 100vh;
}
```